# Bash Validate User Input

Tags: linux, bash, validation

I'm making a small program that lets the user write their name and then proceeds to create a folder with the name they typed. I have this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name:"
read name
mkdir /home/mint/Desktop/$name
```

That's working perfectly fine but I was wondering if there's a way to validate the input so that my program will only accept letters of the alphabet. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You'll want to quote your variables ("$name") -- if you enter a name with spaces, mkdir will give you surprising results.

Comment: For a bash-native way, read up on the `=~` operator and `[[` ... `]]`.

Comment: Also....consider using the `-p` argument to `mkdir`.

Answer (score 2):

There are many many ways to do this:

```
while true; do
    read -p "Enter your name: " name
    case "$name" in
        *[^A-Za-z]*) echo "Only letters are allowed" ;;
        *) break ;;
    esac
done
mkdir ~/Desktop/"$name"
```

You'll want to find a tutorial. There's one here: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/EnglishFrontPage
Or start here on Stack Overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info

Answer (score 0):

Something like this ?

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name:"
read name
name=$(tr -dc [:alpha:] <<<"$name" )
mkdir "/home/mint/Desktop/$name"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "Enter your name:"
read name
if [[ "$name" =~ ^[a-zA-Z]+$ ]]; then
  echo "Creating directory: /home/mint/Desktop/$name"
  mkdir /home/mint/Desktop/$name
else
  echo "Your directory name may only use letters. Please try again."
fi
```

That's using a regular expression that allows only lowercase `a-z` and capital `A-Z` letters.

Comment: Quote your variables.